# 2nd shortcode parameter not changing in my Wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a shortcode with 2 parameters, label and searchButton. The label one works fine, but my searchButton never changes its value.

How I write it in my wordpress blog

```
[expert-locator label="labl" searchButton="hzz"]
```

And in my code

```
add_shortcode('expert-locator', 'expert_locator_shortcode');       

function expert_locator_shortcode( $atts ) {

/*
 * Custom search label and submit button from shortcode parameter
 */
extract( shortcode_atts( 
            array (
                'label' => "Enter skills you're looking for: ",
                'searchButton' => "Submit"
            ), 
            $atts )
);

//extract( $shortcode_params );

global $wpdb;

$authors = array();

//begin form 
expert_form_output( $label, $searchButton ); //function contained in functions.php
}

function expert_form_output( $label = "Enter skills you're looking for: ",
                         $searchButton = "Submit" ) {
?>
<form method="get">
    <label for="searchTerm"><?php echo $label ?></label>
    <input type="text" name="searchTerm" 
        value="<?php if (isset($_GET['searchTerm'])) echo $_GET['searchTerm']; ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $searchButton ?>">
</form>
<?php
}
```

My label changes to whatever I put in my blog, but my searchButton is always "Submit" which is the default value.

Comment: basic debugging: `var_dump(shortcode_atts(....))` and see what's really coming back from that call.

Comment: @MarcB array(2) { ["label"]=> string(4) "labl" ["searchButton"]=> string(6) "Submit" } is what I get. The "labl" is custom, the "Submit" is default even though I changed the parameter in my blog

Answer (score 2):

This issue is [outlined in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Hyphens) and is caused by your use of a hyphen in the shortcode name. You should change the hyphen to an underscore:

```
add_shortcode('expert_locator', 'expert_locator_shortcode');
```

Also from that same link:

> IMPORTANT TIP - Don't use camelCase or UPPER-CASE for your `$atts` attribute names

Comment: changed it...did not fix anything

Answer (score 1):

So after looking at the codex posted in another answer, I tried changing my "submitButton" to "submitbutton" and it worked...